# URL http://localhost:8000/admin/ redirects to wrong page

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to reach the Django admin page but  when I type in http://localhost:8000/admin/ it pops up with my web application instead.

For more context I have two url.py's in separate folders.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.project_list, name='list'),
    path('<slug:project_slug>/', views.project_detail, name='detail')
]
```

and...

```
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('budget.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

I'm not sure why http://localhost:8000/admin/ doesn't go to Django's admin page but if anyone has any suggestions that would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your project level urls.py place admin url in top.
Like this

```
urlpatterns = [
       path('admin/',admin.site.urls),
       path('',include('budget.urls'))
   ]
```

Comment: I've made the following change but it still seems to load my web application :/

Comment: In my last answer i forgot to put "/" after admin, so add / after admin

Comment: i will suggest whenever you use slug field,always write something before it

Comment: Convert your slug url to path('detail/<slug:project_slug>/', views.project_detail, name='detail')

Answer (score 1):

Change urlpatterns order here:

```py
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('budget.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

like this:

```py
from django.urls import path, include


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('budget.urls')),
```

In your code pattern `path('<slug:project_slug>/', views.project_detail, name='detail')` resolve before `path('admin',admin.site.urls),`.

[See Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request)